# Is there a way to get Not Enough Items to recognize foreign crafting tables?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

Whenever I play the Lord of the Rings mod for minecraft 1.7.10, NEI doesn't recognize all the different furnaces/ crafting benches. Is there a way to get NEI to recognize them, or is that outside NEI limits?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

NEI supports various plugins that expand it to recognize different methods of crafting if they do not support NEI natively, this plugin should support the Lord of the Rings mod (note that I have not tried either this plugin or the LOTR mod).

http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/mapping-and-modding/minecraft-mods/1289387-1-5-2-lord-of-the-rings-nei-plugin

Comment: Is there a later version of the plugin?